# Discord.js bot doesn't get the image with args name

Tags: discord.js

The command is this way: ?pokegif Mewtwo Mega X then it doesn't send the image. But when I write ?pokegif Mewtwo-megax it appears. But I want to make it as first example

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

exports.run = function(korra, message, args) {
    let sprite = message.content.toLowerCase().split(' ').slice(1).join(" ");
    let pokemonurl = (`https://play.pokemonshowdown.com/sprites/xyani-shiny/${sprite.replace(/ /g,'-')}.gif`);
    let names = args.slice(0).join(' ');
    if (!sprite) return message.channel.send("You need to write a pokemon name!!");
    const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setDescription('You have requested this pokemon:')
        .setImage(pokemonurl)
        message.channel.send(embed);      
}

exports.conf = {
    enabled: true, 
    guildOnly: true, 
    aliases: [],
    permLevel: 0 
  };

  exports.help = {
    name: 'shiny', 
    description: 'Shows shiny pokemons',
    usage: 'shiny <pikachu>'
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

> ?pokegif Mewtwo Mega X then it doesn't send the image. But when I
>   write ?pokegif Mewtwo-megax it appears.

This is happening because the file name is *mewtwo-megax.gif* **not** *mewtwo-mega-x.gif*.

Instead of saying *?pokegif Mewtwo Mega X*, say *?pokegif Mewtwo MegaX*.

You can see all file names at [pokemonshowdown](https://play.pokemonshowdown.com/sprites/xyani-shiny/)